# Targeting the most appropriate API

Tags: android

Currently, I tend to target all my app development to API 8, so that I can hit the largest number of devices 'out there', basically from Android 2.2 upwards.

Do any experienced Android developers reading this have a perspective on what features, as a developer am I 'missing out' on, and more importantly, what are my users missing out on?  In this day and age, what API is the 'best' one for my apps to target? Or is there no such thing, and each app should be targeted for a given API on its merits?

I'm not looking for pointers such as read the android developer docs (I have, or at least what I consider the salient parts), I'm more interested in the views of experienced developers as to how they decide which API to target.

Thanks.

Comment: I target Android 2.1 upwards, simply because my own main phone is running 2.1 :)

Comment: 2.3 API 10. Covering 80% of phones. I reckon we can lower it though with no coding issues. Its like this because API 10 was a good place to start, we had one already. And our clients buy new devices anyway.

Comment: It really depends on the app imho. I usually start with 2.1. and go up depending on the features of the app. E.g. if it makes use of the camera API, selecting a higher requirement makes sense since you have major improvements and more features. Many things can also be backported *(see ActionBarSherlock, compat lib, ...)*, so a higher requirement is not always neccessary for newer features. Basically, if don't miss something specific, go as low as possible *(though < 2.1. doesn't really make sense anymore)*.

Comment: i hope from 2.2 is a right choice -- we normally target api 16 wiith a compatibility from 2.2 as it will look as if made for api v 16 but still ll be compatible through out all versions i personally feel targeting 2.3 is the best options as most phones are in this category but eventually all ll shift 2 a btr version

Comment: on Android 2.2 and lower GC acts differently from Android 2.3 and higher. It affects freeze times on your main thread when GC kicks in - so you might want to consider this fact in case your app is memory istensive. Check this out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk&feature=player_detailpage#t=638s

Answer (score 2):

if you set your target and minSdkVersion to 7 and use support (compatibility) library v4, then your app will support nearly 95% of all android phones, and still you are able to use modern features of newer APIs (by using support library).

Answer (score 0):

I usually target the minimum API required by the apps functionality. If there is a minor feature needing a higher API, I make it optional instead of increasing the minimum for the whole app. In addition to using ActionBarSherlock and the compatibility libraries, I occasionally back port a few things from later APIs to keep the current basis.

While I decide the minimum on a per app basis, most of my apps target 2.1, as they were written almost one and a half years ago. Now days, I have new apps target 2.2, though I plan to change it to 2.3 very soon.

I guess my point is that there is no defined minimum API target. You should choose the one which offers maximum user reach, along with as much major functionality as possible. UI elements like the action bar and ViewPager can be used via libraries, and the ones not available in libraries can sometimes be back ported. However, it is usually not worth it to sacrifice users running a lower API version just for a better UI.